# Definition of Differentiability for $f:\Bbb{R}^{3}\to\Bbb{R}^{2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

A function $f:\Bbb{R}^{3}\to\Bbb{R}^{2}$ is said to be $\mathbf{differentiable}$ at $a\in\Bbb{R}^{3}$ if there exists a $2\times3$ matrix $A$ such that

\begin{align}
\dfrac{\lvert f(a+h)-f(a)-Ah\rvert}{\lvert h\rvert}\to0
\end{align}

as $h\to0$. Show that the partial derivatives $\partial_{x_{j}}f^{i}(a)$ exist at $a$ where we write $f=(f^{1},f^{2})$ where each element $f^{j}$ is a real-valued function of three variables and that

\begin{align}
A=(\partial_{x_{j}}f^{i}(a))
\end{align}

is the $\mathbf{Jacobian}$ matrix of $f$.

I'm not too sure where to start, and yes, I am aware that a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3168395/definition-of-differentiability) has been asked before but I am still quite confused considering this is a map from $\Bbb{R}^{3}$ to $\Bbb{R}^{2}$. Appreciate if anyone could provide with some pointers, thanks.

Comment: One way to start working on this problem is to show that the partial derivates really are your only options to form the total derivative A. That is, if A is a total derivative, any other inputs in the Jacobian than the partial derivatives are not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote $\{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ $\mathbb R^3$  canonical basis. For $u\in \mathbb R$ and $1 \le j \le 3$ you have

$$\begin{aligned}\frac{\Vert f(a+u.e_j) -f(a) -A(u.e_j)\Vert}{\Vert u.e_j \Vert} &= \frac{\Vert f(a+u.e_j) -f(a) -A(ue_j)\Vert}{\vert u \vert}\\
&= \frac{\Vert f(a+u.e_j) -f(a) -u A_j\Vert}{\vert u \vert}\\
\end{aligned}$$

where $A_j$ is the $j$-th colum of $A$. And if you look at the $i$-th coordinate, you get

$$\lim\limits_{u \to 0} \frac{ f^i(a+u.e_j) -f^i(a) }{ u } = A_j^i$$ which means exactly

$$\begin{align}
A=(\partial_{x_{j}}f^{i}(a))
\end{align}$$